# Show the center coordinate of the object tracking bounding box

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I would like to know how I can print the tracking coordinate rectangle onto the video. I want the coordinate of the center point of the rectangle and, of course, I want: if the tracker is moving, the coordinate is also updated.

I tried to use:

```
 cv2.putText(frame, **??** , (100,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50), 2);
```

somewhat like this inside the loop, but I cannot figure it out.

```
import cv2
import sys

(major_ver, minor_ver, subminor_ver) = (cv2.__version__).split('.')

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    # Set up tracker.
    # Instead of MIL, you can also use

    tracker_types = ['BOOSTING', 'MIL','KCF', 'TLD', 'MEDIANFLOW', 'GOTURN', 'MOSSE', 'CSRT']
    tracker_type = tracker_types[2]

    if int(minor_ver) < 3:
        tracker = cv2.Tracker_create(tracker_type)
    else:
        if tracker_type == 'BOOSTING':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerBoosting_create()
        if tracker_type == 'MIL':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()
        if tracker_type == 'KCF':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
        if tracker_type == 'TLD':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerTLD_create()
        if tracker_type == 'MEDIANFLOW':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
        if tracker_type == 'GOTURN':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerGOTURN_create()
        if tracker_type == 'MOSSE':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create()
        if tracker_type == "CSRT":
            tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()

    # Read video
    video = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

    # Exit if video not opened.
    if not video.isOpened():
        print ("Could not open video")
        sys.exit()

    # Read first frame.
    ok, frame = video.read()
    if not ok:
        print ('Cannot read video file')
        sys.exit()
    
    # Define an initial bounding box
    bbox = (287, 23, 86, 320)

    # Uncomment the line below to select a different bounding box
    bbox = cv2.selectROI(frame, False)

    # Initialize tracker with first frame and bounding box
    ok = tracker.init(frame, bbox)

    while True:
        # Read a new frame
        ok, frame = video.read()
        if not ok:
            break
        
        # Start timer
        timer = cv2.getTickCount()

        # Update tracker
        ok, bbox = tracker.update(frame)

        # Calculate Frames per second (FPS)
        fps = cv2.getTickFrequency() / (cv2.getTickCount() - timer);

        # Draw bounding box
        if ok:
            # Tracking success
            p1 = (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]))
            p2 = (int(bbox[0] + bbox[2]), int(bbox[1] + bbox[3]))
            cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, (255,0,0), 2, 1)
        else :
            # Tracking failure
            cv2.putText(frame, "Tracking failure detected", (100,80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,(0,0,255),2)

        # Display tracker type on frame
        cv2.putText(frame, tracker_type + " Tracker", (100,20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50),2);
    
        # Display FPS on frame
        cv2.putText(frame, "FPS : " + str(int(fps)), (100,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50), 2);

        # Display result
        cv2.imshow("Tracking", frame)

        # Exit if ESC pressed
        k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
        if k == 27 : break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the center of rectangle by dividing across the length and breadth of the rectangle obtained from variables `p1` and `p2`.

Coordinate: `p1` --> `(x1, y1)`

Coordinate: `p2` --> `(x2, y2)`

To find the center of the rectangle divide `(x1+x2)/2` and `(y1+y2)/2`

`rectangle_center = (int(p1[0] + p2[0])/2, int(p1[1] + p2[1])/2)`

Within `cv2.putText()` place the above variable as a string --> `str(rectangle_center)`